# Не работает audio.pause()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('html').keydown(function(e){

      //музыка. Insert - включить, Delete - выключить

      const audio = new Audio('https://zvukogram.com/index.php?r=site/download&id=6600');
      audio.autoplay = false;
      audio.loop = true;

      if (e.keyCode == 45) {
        audio.play();
      }

      if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        audio.pause();
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В чем может быть проблема? Почему аудио по нажатию нужной кнопки запускается, а по нажатию другой кнопки для выключения не выключается? Не работает pause(). В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так хотели думаю

```js
const audio = new Audio('https://zvukogram.com/index.php?r=site/download&id=6600');
      audio.autoplay = false;
      audio.loop = true;



$('html').keydown(function(e){

      //музыка. Insert - включить, Delete - выключить
      
      if (e.keyCode == 45) {
        audio.play();
      }

      if (e.keyCode == 46) {
        audio.pause();
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Выша проблема что вы создаёте `audio` и обрабатываете его тут же. Когда нужно ставить обработчик вне создания `audio`. Следующий раз он опять зайдет и снова создаст `audio`, а что с предыдущим?